# Indetermined nested checkboxes in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with nested checkboxes and having problems with setting indeterminate to the parent checkbox (top level).
It works for the sub-checkboxes and sub-sub-checkboxes but someComplete() always returns false and doesn't set the parent checkbox to indeterminate. This happens beacuse the component is used in several places in the document.
I tried looking for class="mat-checkbox-indeterminate" to set the parent to indeterminate but that won't work since the component is redendered in several places with different parent-checkboxes. How can I specify the parent checkbox to only check its children and set to indeterminate?
Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

HTML:

```
  <div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
    <mat-checkbox role="checkbox"
                  color="primary"
                  [checked]="checkBox.isAllChecked"
                  [indeterminate]="someComplete()"
                  (change)="setAll($event.checked)">
      {{checkBox.name}}
    </mat-checkbox>        
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let subCheckBox of checkBox.subCheckBoxes">
        <mat-checkbox role="checkbox"
                      color="primary"
                      [(ngModel)]="subCheckBox.isChecked"
                      [indeterminate]="someSubComplete(subCheckBox)"
                      (change)="setAllSub(subCheckBox, $event.checked)"
                      (ngModelChange)="updateAllComplete()">
          {{subCheckBox.name}}
        </mat-checkbox>
        <div *ngIf="subCheckBox.subCheckBoxes.length > 0">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let subSubCheckBox of subCheckBox.subCheckBoxes">
              <mat-checkbox role="checkbox"
              color="primary"
              [(ngModel)]="subSubCheckBox.isChecked"
              (ngModelChange)="updateAllSubComplete(subCheckBox)">
              {{subSubCheckBox.name}}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
 updateAllComplete() {
    this.checkBox.isAllChecked = this.checkBox.subCheckBoxes?.every(t => t.isChecked);
  }

  updateAllSubComplete(subCheckBox: SubCheckBoxModel) {
    subCheckBox.isChecked = subCheckBox.subCheckBoxes?.every(t => t.isChecked);
    this.updateAllComplete();
  }

  someComplete(): boolean {
    if (this.checkBox.subCheckBoxes == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return this.checkBox.subCheckBoxes.filter(t => t.isChecked).length > 0 && !this.checkBox.isAllChecked;
  }

  someSubComplete(subCheckBox: SubCheckBoxModel): boolean {
    if (subCheckBox.subCheckBoxes == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return subCheckBox.subCheckBoxes.filter(t => t.isChecked).length > 0 && !subCheckBox.isChecked;
  }

  setAll(isChecked: boolean) {
    this.checkBox.isAllChecked = isChecked;
    if (this.checkBox.subCheckBoxes == null) {
      return;
    }
    for(let subCheckBox of this.checkBox.subCheckBoxes){
      subCheckBox.isChecked = isChecked;
      subCheckBox.subCheckBoxes.forEach(t => (t.isChecked = isChecked));
    }
  }

  setAllSub(subCheckBox: SubCheckBoxModel, isChecked: boolean) {
    subCheckBox.isChecked = isChecked;
    if (this.checkBox.subCheckBoxes == null) {
      return;
    }
    subCheckBox.subCheckBoxes.forEach(t => (t.isChecked = isChecked));
  }
```

Models:

```
export class SubCheckBoxModel {
    id: any;
    name: string;
    isChecked: boolean;
    subCheckBoxes: SubCheckBoxModel[];
}

export class CheckBoxModel {
    id: any;
    name: string;
    isAllChecked: boolean;
    subCheckBoxes: SubCheckBoxModel[];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have created one demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5v5amd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Can you please explain where exactly did you got stuck? Thanks!